# How to SELECT DISTINCT of one field and other fields From INNER JOIN table

Tags: select, distinct, inner-join, field

I use PHP and MySQL and I
have 2 tables:

- table score: have fields 'user_id' and 'score'
- table user: have fields 'user_id' and 'user_name'

People play game then store user_id and score in table 'score' every time game was ended. There are many rows for a single user in table score.

What I want?
  I want to select top 10 players with distinct user_name to show on the list, so what is the correct sql? Code below is now my current sql, but it's not show result what I want.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT * FROM score as t1
  INNER JOIN user AS t2 ON t1.user_id=t2.user_id
  WHERE score>0
  ORDER BY t1.score DESC
  LIMIT 10
```

What is the mistake for this?

Comment: The correct code modified from Kent's is <br/>select user_name, max(score) as maxscore 
from score, user
 where score.user_id=user.user_id and score>0 
group by user_name 
order by maxscore desc 
      LIMIT 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this work? (not tested)

```
    select username, max(score) as maxscore 
from score, user
 where score.userid=user.userid and score>0 
group by username 
order by maxscore desc
```

Answer (score 0):

The following sql will return the top 10 highest scoring players sorted by their best score (not a top 10 of scores, but a top 10 of players).

```
SELECT
    u.user_name,
    max(s.score)
FROM 
    score as s
    INNER JOIN [user] AS u
        ON s.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE
    score > 0
GROUP BY
    u.user_name
ORDER BY 
    2 DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: sorry for all , I want distinct top 10 players

Comment: Even remove [ ] the result still not be 10 top score players. It shows many rows of duplicate users with high score.

Comment: The bracket was to distinguished your "user" table from the system table named "User".  In mysql this may not be necessary however.

Comment: I updated my answer to better suit your issue.  I'm unable to test it right now, does it execute?

Comment: Thanks viper34j, the answer from your new code is not show score. It show only user_name.

Comment: Try it again.  I updated the Order By to sort by column 2 descending.